# How can I analyze the user productivity in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

I need to analyse the team's productivity by user.
I would like to see how many tasks each user burned, but I would like to see too, the sum of the work planned by each burned tasks (the "Remaining Work" column when the task was created).

Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I analyze the user productivity in Azure DevOps?

There is a side plan Work details under the view options for Sprints:

[image]

If you [set sprint capacity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/set-capacity?view=azure-devops) correctly, you will find the work details for team and user.

If you want to see how many tasks each user burned, you can add a Query to get the list:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: In the work details I can't see the "planned work" of the finished tasks :(
When the tasks is moved to done, the "Remanig Work" is set to null.
In this page I can see only the "Remanig Work" of the Tasks not finished.
I know that this is the correct, but I would like to see the sum of "Remanig Work" that was inputed in Tasks finished versus users associated in this tasks.